# Unable to find TableRecycleGridLayout to fix Kivy code

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm getting an error trying to create a table in KivyMD

`ValueError: TableRecycleGridLayout.orientation is set to an invalid option 'vertical'. Must be one of: ['lr-tb', 'tb-lr', 'rl-tb', 'tb-rl', 'lr-bt', 'bt-lr', 'rl-bt', 'bt-rl']`

It's telling me I need to change orientation to something other than 'vertical' but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the MDDataTable you just need to add "orientation="lr-tb" or one of the other values the give. This worked for me with Kivy==2.0.0.

Example:

```
table = MDDataTable(orientation="lr-tb",
                    pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
                    size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
                    column_data=[("Food", dp(30)),("Calories", dp(30))],
                    row_data=[("Burger", "300"),("Oats", "50")])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix which was to simply remove orientation:'vertical' from "TableRecycleGridLayout:" in kivymd/uix/datatables.py as shown below:

```
TableRecycleGridLayout:
    id: row_controller
    key_selection: "selectable"
    cols: root.total_col_headings
    cols_minimum: root.cols_minimum
    default_size: None, dp(52)
    default_size_hint: 1, None
    size_hint: None, None
    height: self.minimum_height
    width: self.minimum_width
    multiselect: True
    touch_multiselect: True
```

Now run your program. Share your comments.