# Kivymd MDDataTable failed to execute

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I was trying this simple code about MDDataTable, but it always gives me error every time I execute it. Recently I successfully ran different KivyMD function but this simple table is giving me headaches.

**Python Code**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp

class Demo(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen  = Screen()
        table = MDDataTable(orientation = "lr-tb",
                            column_data = [
                                ("Food",dp(30)),
                                ("Calories", dp(30))
                            ])
        screen.add_widget(table)
        return screen
Demo().run()
```

**Error**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/purbar/dataTabols.py", line 16, in <module>
     Demo().run()
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/purbar/dataTabols.py", line 9, in build
     table = MDDataTable(orientation = "lr-tb",
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\datatables.py", line 923, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\theming.py", line 907, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\modalview.py", line 187, in __init__
     super(ModalView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\anchorlayout.py", line 68, in __init__
     super(AnchorLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\purbar\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter the error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument
```

it is telling you that the `__init__()` method for the class `object` is being called with an unexpected argument. The `object` class is the base class for all python classes (See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#object)). In python, when you create a new instance of some class, its `__init__()` method is called with whatever arguments you provided. A normal `__init__()` will grab the key word arguments that it recognizes, and pass any remaining keyword arguments to its base class. This will continue until the `__init__()` for the `object` class is finally called. The `__init__()` method for `object` takes no arguments, so any keyword arguments that survive to the `object` class `__init__()` will throw the error you are seeing. That will happen if you provide a keyword argument to an `__init__()` method that is unrecognized. In your case that unrecognized argument is `orientation`. The `MDDataTable` class does not recognize `orientation` as a keyword argument, so it gets passed all the way down to the `object` class and the error is thrown.

TLDR: just remove the `orientation = "lr-tb"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this link: [Unable to find TableRecycleGridLayout to fix Kivy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481888/unable-to-find-tablerecyclegridlayout-to-fix-kivy-code), this is (I guess) your solution to avoid "vertical" error message.
It didn't work for me, so I removed pair "orientation: vertical" from template for **TableRecycleGridLayout** in *kivymd.uix.datatables.py* and it solved this problem. This is maybe kivimd bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing `orientation='tb-lr'` throws a `ValueError` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481888/unable-to-find-tablerecyclegridlayout-to-fix-kivy-code)), but including it gave the same `TypeError` you experienced.

As of now I was able to solve it by installing KivyMD from source (i.e. from https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD) like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git --depth 1
cd KivyMD
pip install .
```