# TypeError: object.init() adding datatable

Tags: python, kivymd

I was getting this error and attempted to copy/paste from another [Unable to find TableRecycleGridLayout to fix Kivy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481888/unable-to-find-tablerecyclegridlayout-to-fix-kivy-code) but received another error?

```
def build(self):
screen = Screen()
table = MDDataTable(orientation="lr-tb",
                    pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
                    size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
                    column_data=[("Food", dp(30)), ("Calories", dp(30))],
                    row_data=[("Burger", "300"), ("Oats", "50")])
screen.add_widget(table)
return screen
```

with the error: TypeError: object.init() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

im just learning so i assume its something simple i am doing but not seeing it. Any suggestions?